# How to custom UICollectionView to left align in horizontal direction

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Anyone please guide me how to make UICollectionView to be

1. Left align
2. limit number of rows to 3

like the image below (in popular lists)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a solution. So I made it using Scrollview + StackView. That make life happy again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom UICollectionViewLayout

The key point is to layout elements manually by calculating yourself

here is a similar [example in github](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout)

And you need to override the two following method

```
  override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {  }
  

  override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {   }
```